# node js https not working behind corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, https, proxy, request

```
it always gives :
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <hostname without http or https>
    at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
STATUS: undefined
```

My code is as follows:-

```js
var Http = require('https');
var str = "";
var options = {
    hostname: '<host name without http or https>',
    path: '<path>',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset:utf-8',
        'Content-Length': payload.length,
        'User-Agent': 'Node.js/0.12.7',
        'Proxy-Connections': 'keep-alive'
    }
};

var req = Http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf-8');
    res.on('data', function(response) {
        str += response;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        return exits.success(str);
    });
});
req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + e.statusCode);
    exits.error('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
req.write(payload);
req.end();
```

I have already tried following:-
 - setting proxy and https-proxy
 - removing http or https from host name

Please help me resolving this issue.

Comment: You need to fill in the actual `hostname` and `path` in the `options` object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I tried that already but not helped anything.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `agent` parameter in your request option with so it can cope with the corporate proxy.

```
var Http = require('https');
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

// Use the environment variables or set proxy server manually.
var proxyServer = process.env.http_proxy ||
                  process.env.HTTP_PROXY ||
                  process.env.https_proxy ||
                  process.env.HTTPS_PROXY ||
                 'https://168.63.76.32:3128';

var options = {
    agent: new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyServer ),       // <-- proxy agent
    hostname: '<host name without http or https>',
    path: '<path>',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset:utf-8',
        'Content-Length': payload.length,
        'User-Agent': 'Node.js/0.12.7',
        'Proxy-Connections': 'keep-alive'
    }
};
```

See proxy agent documentation for more info:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-agent

https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-proxy-agent